# SSRS Time Format wrong

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, reporting-services, formatting

I am using SSRS for a report but I'm having a issue with my times. In SQL they are coming out how I want them as 00:00:00:00 but in SSRS FastestSegmentTime and SlowestSegmentTime is coming out as 00:00:00:00.0000000. I have tried formatting the textbox it goes into but nothing seems to work. if anyone has an idea on how to fix this it would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Thomas James

```
DECLARE
@vnuID int = 1212,
@StartDate datetime = '30/10/2013',
@EndDate datetime = '30/11/2013'


SELECT  
    FastestSegmentTime = MIN(CAST(tblTrace.trFinish - tblTrace.trStart AS TIME(2))),
    SlowestSegmentTime = MAX(CAST(tblTrace.trFinish - tblTrace.trStart AS TIME(2))),
    AvgSegmentTime = CAST(DATEADD(ms, 1000 * AVG(DATEDIFF(SECOND, tblTrace.trStart , tblTrace.trFinish)),0) AS TIME(2))
FROM 
    tblTrace
    INNER JOIN tblUsers ON usrID = tr_usrID
WHERE 
    (tblTrace.trFinish IS NOT NULL)
    AND (tblTrace.trObjectType LIKE 'Segment%') 
    AND (tblTrace.tr_vnuID = @vnuID) 
    AND (tblTrace.trStart BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
    AND (tblUsers.usrEmail NOT LIKE '%@test%')
```

Comment: You didn't show how you format the times. Time and date types have NO format. They are formatted only when you convert them to text, implicitly or explicitly. Where and how do you display the values? What's the format of the report fields?

Comment: Don't forget your report and your sql server engine can have different language format too. You can specify for example to a report to display in german so like this your money and date are formated for germany. Your sql server is perhaps, probably in english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of converting `FastestSegmentTime` column to **time(2)**, convert it to **datetime**. Then in SSRS in textbox expression write this: `=Format(Fields!time.Value,"HH:mm:ss:ff")`. It will display the value in desired format.